# algorithm to google questions with three answers

Tags: python, html, algorithm, nlp-question-answering

I'm currently working on a little project where I get one question and three answers and one of them is correct. I need to find this one. Right now I make a request to google and search in the source code of the results for each answer. Unfortunately, it does not work very well. These are my problems:

1. The question is not google ready formulated
2. The question is negative
3. The answers are sometimes different in google (eg. Answer: "X & Y", Google: "X and Y)
4. I cannot find the right answer on the google-result page.

I feel like I cannot hardcode every single rule for every possible type of question, because there are simply too many.

Is there something like an algorithm for that? Or what would be the best procedure to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: Your requirements aren't entirely clear, but the problem looks like a mix of the fields of Information Retrieval and Natural Language Processing, at least.  There's no single algorithm that you could use here AFAIK.

Comment: I second @snakecharmerb there is not single algorithm to solve you problem. Try to reformulate and explain what you have tried. In this question current form, it seems you just googled the question to see if they are result. Give it more time and try to analyze the problem at end to give more focused task.